# How to print python statements in k8s container when running a java application through sub process

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, subprocess

I tried making stdout, stdin as None and also subprocess.STDOUT. My container logs are still showing the logs of app.jar. I want the container to show the print statements and the application logs. Disabling logs completely is making the container print no logs. I do not want to clutter my container with application logs for viewers but want to show where the execution is currently

```
**code.py**
pro = subprocess.Popen(
    ['/bin/java', '-jar', '/apps/ZAP_2.10.0/app.jar',
     '-daemon', '-host', 'localhost', '-port', '8080', '-dir', '', '-silent', '-config', 'api.key=ZAP',
     '-config', 'api.addrs.addr.regex=true', '-config', 'connection.timeoutInSecs=300'], shell=False,
    stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)


print("App is running!")
```

Docker File:

```
RUN wget app.zip &&
       unzip app.zip \
       rm -f app.zip
CMD ["/bin/bash", "script.sh"]
```

My script.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash`
source venv/bin/activate`
python code.py
```

My code.py has the content I  mentioned in the question. I am deploying it as 'Deployment' config.

Comment: Can you show us how your dockerfile is launching your app? What is your CMD and/or ENTRYPOINT? Also how your Deployment (assuming you are using Deployment here) is configured on kubernetes side?

Comment: @Andrew I have updated the question with the docker file and shell script I am using

Comment: Are you sure your print statement its'n showed? It should be your very first log line.

Comment: @pbacterio My logs are only showing at the end after app.jar finishes executing. The print statements are not showing whilst execution. After the job finishes, all the print statements are coming at the end.

Comment: Is there a purpose for which you want a virtual environment inside the container ?

Comment: @dejdej That source venv is part of the source code already. I am working on a part of the branch

Comment: You should enable output buffering. Add -u parameter. python -u code.py.  https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/06/26/how-to-check-if-pythons-output-buffering-is-enabled/